# ShellSettingsManager with mocked IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to unit test a code that uses IServiceProvider to create an instance of ShellSettingsManager.

```
    public class MyClass : IMyClass
    {
        SettingsManager settingsManager;
        WritableSettingsStore userSettingsStore;

        public MyClass(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            settingsManager = new ShellSettingsManager(serviceProvider);
            userSettingsStore = settingsManager.GetWritableSettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);
        }
    }
```

Here is the test that creates a Mock (using Moq) for IServiceProvider:

```
    var moqServiceProvider = new Mock<IServiceProvider>();
    moqServiceProvider.Setup(item => item.GetService(typeof(SVsSettingsManager))).Returns(typeof(SVsSettingsManager));

    var myClass = new  MyClass(moqServiceProvider.Object);
```

The following exception is thrown at the line

```
new ShellSettingsManager(serviceProvider)
```

"System.NotSupportedException: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsSettingsManager'".

Looks like either I am not getting the correct service or ShellSettingsManager does not support mocked IserviceProvider. How can I mock IServiceProvider to be able to create an instance of ShellSettingsManager?

Comment: without knowing what `ShellSettingsManager` does with the provider there is no way for us to assess the actual problem.

Comment: Secondly that service locator approach is not very maintainable. Dependencies should be explicitly injected.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Also noticed that `.Returns(typeof(SVsSettingsManager));` is returning a type and not an object instance, which could probably be the root of the problem.

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, ShellSettingsManager is a class in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Settings namespace, this is the gateway class to reach for the settings stored inside the Visual Studio. I also tried .Returns(moqServiceProvider.Object); This didn't work

Comment: You would need an actual instance of `ShellSettingsManager`. `.Returns(moqServiceProvider.Object)` wont work since that is the mock of `IServiceProvider`